# Why can we use the identity matrix when defining the characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

We begin with $$\lambda v = Tv$$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, $v$ is an eigenvector, and $T$ is the transformation in question.
We state $$\lambda v - Tv = 0$$ We then must state $$(\lambda I - T)v = 0$$What allows us to bring in $I$, the identity matrix? I understand that subtraction of a linear transformation (or matrix) from a scalar is ill-defined, but what permits us to multiply $\lambda$ by $I$? Would a more rigorous evaluation be
\begin{align*}
\lambda v - Tv &= \lambda Iv - Tv \\ &= (\lambda I - T)v
\end{align*}
where the identity matrix provides a multiplicative identity of some sorts? I understand that $I \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F})$, so I am wondering how it can be the identity for $v \in M_{n \times 1}(\mathbb{F})$?

The reason I ask is that I am proving Cayley-Hamilton for a diagonal matrix, and I have come upon the following:

\begin{align*}
\chi(t) 
 &= det(D-tI) \\ 
 &= \prod_{i=1}^{n}d_{ii}-t \\
 &= (d_{11} - t)(d_{22} - t) \cdots (d_{nn} - t)
\end{align*}

Consider
\begin{align*}
\chi([D]) &= (d_{11}I - D)(d_{22}I - D) \cdots (d_{nn}I - D)
\end{align*}

Where does the $I$ come from?

The underlying question is really this:

> I understand that $I \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F})$, so I am wondering how it can be the identity for $v \in M_{n \times 1}(\mathbb{F})$?

Comment: I suppose the simple answer of factoring $v$ on the right is it...

Comment: Guess I don't understand what you find confusing about $\,I v = v\,$.

Comment: It is mostly the last bit, about Cayley-Hamilton @dxiv

Comment: "Substituting" $D$ into the characteristic polynomial is done by replacing $t^n$ with $D^n$. $D^0 = I$ so we replace $d_{ii}t^0$ with $d_{ii}I$

Comment: So it is as trivial as simply writing it as $(d_{11}t^0 - t)(d_{22}t^0 - t) \cdots (d_{nn}t^0 - t)$ @OgglieOstrich ?

Comment: The identity matrix $I\in M_{n}(F)$ satisfies $AI=A$ for any $A\in M_{m\times n}(F)$, and $IB=B$ for any $B\in M_{n\times p}(F)$, as you can easily check. So it's more than just an identity element of the ring $M_n(F)$.

Comment: @user129393192 But your latest edit "*how it can be the identity*" only emphasizes that the question is really about why $\,I v = v\,$. See also related questions [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799467/), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55724/), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536815/).

Comment: Any linear operator that maps $M_{n \times 1}(\mathbb{F})$ to itself can be written as an element of $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F})$. In this case the identity operator $\text{id}: M_{n \times 1}(\mathbb{F}) \to M_{n \times 1}(\mathbb{F})$ can be written as $\text{id}(v) = I \cdot v$.

Comment: It might be better to think of the polynomial as a sequence of coefficients $(p_0,...,p_n, 0,...)$ (all but a finite number being zero). Then the polynomial can be 'evaluated' at any element of a ring by considering the element $p_0 I +p_1 X+\cdots + p_n X^n$, where $I$ is the identity of the ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several questions; I will just try to answer the main one:

> "I understand that $I \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F})$, so I am wondering how it can be the identity for $v \in M_{n \times 1}(\mathbb{F})$?"

First, in general, vector spaces (in your case $M_{n \times 1}(\mathbb F)$ or better known as $\mathbb F^n$) don't come with multiplicative identities. In fact vector spaces don't even need any multiplication within itself; it just needs to be an abelian group with a single operation reminiscent of addition. This is the case with $\mathbb F^n$. It has a well-defined vector addition and it satisfies a bunch of rules on how the field $\mathbb F$ acts on it. There is no unified notion of multiplication in $\mathbb F^n$.

The situation you are seeing with $I \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb F)$ acting on $v \in \mathbb F^n$ like an "identity" is an entirely new phenomenon that $\mathbb F^n$ enjoys **in addition to** its the vector space properties. $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb F)$ forms a structure called a **ring**, which is a crippled field: both addition and multiplication are defined in it but division may not always be possible.

Just like the field $\mathbb F$ acts on $\mathbb F^n$, through scalar multiplication, to give it its vector space property, the ring $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb F)$ also acts on $\mathbb F^n$, through left matrix-vector multiplication, to give it a separate property called a **left module**. One of the central requirements of a left module is exactly what you noticed: that the identity of the ring must also act like an identity on the module elements.

Comment: Can I ask if this means that an element of $\mathbb{F}$ is both a left and right module? For example, if $[A] = [a_{ij}]$ then $c[A] = [A]c$ for $c \in \mathbb{F}$?

Comment: @user129393192 by default scalar multiplication is defined as acting on the left but yes it can also be defined as acting on the right through that equation.

Comment: I see. I ask because I want to know if something like this is possible: $(d_{11}[Q]^{-1}[I][Q] - [Q]^{-1}[D][Q])  = [Q]^{-1}(d_{11}[I] - [D])[Q]$.

Comment: @user129393192 Don't see anything wrong with that